# Como adquirir insight para novas tecnologias e técnicas de programação?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, princípios-de-programação

Está com cara de sujeita a opinião/debate, mas queria tentar encaixar uma pergunta nessa linha.

É importante para um bom programador saber avaliar *trade-offs* (prós e contras de se adotar uma determinada abordagem ou tecnologia para resolver um problema).

O que pode ser considerado razoavelmente "ponto pacífico" e objetivo em termos de nos capacitar para ter melhores *insights* na hora de avaliar as vantagens e desvantagens de uma tecnologia nova, uma nova técnica de programação ou aplicar esse conhecimento na resolução de problemas da área?

Não precisa ser uma resposta 100% assertiva, acho que basta ser útil para uma maioria na comunidade, principalmente iniciantes.

Espero respostas do pessoal mais novato também. Certamente as gerações mais novas que cresceram com a Internet devem ter algo a dizer no que se refere a adquirir informação, filtrar e transformar em conhecimento nos dias de hoje.

Comment: Dei o +1 porque acho um debate válido e, decerto, importante para muitos programadores. :-) Contudo, sou obrigado a confessar que não sei se é o "lugar ideal" por causa do caráter opinativo e de debate. Vamos ver o que o resto do pessoal pensa.

Comment: +1 @LuizFelipe a pergunta é realmente interessante. Ele poderia ser feita no META, talvez? porque já seria um debate que envolve toda a comunidade...

Comment: Acho que ela não é "meta" o suficiente para ser discutida no Meta. Discutir a possibilidade de reabertura é algo que eu entendo que faria sentido perguntar no Meta, por exemplo (não que eu particularmente esteja sugerindo reabrir), agora a pergunta em si é sobre programação e por isso caberia fazer mais aqui do que no Meta.